# Google Earth Web - network link

Tags: kml, google-earth

**Question:** do network links work in Google Earth Web (Web, not desktop)?

In Google Earth Web, I would like to call a kml file with network link.

Here is the code of init.kml the file imported manually in Google Earth:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Folder>
    <name>QI01</name>
    <visibility>1</visibility>
    <open>1</open>
    <NetworkLink>
        <name>test</name>
        <visibility>1</visibility>
        <Link>
          <href>zzz.kml</href>
          <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
          <refreshInterval>5</refreshInterval>
        </Link>
        <flyToView>1</flyToView>
    </NetworkLink>
</Folder>
</kml>
```

And the zzz.kml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Place 1</name>
        <description>
        <![CDATA[
        Place number 1
        ]]>
        </description>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-76.661005,46.428222,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Place 2</name>
        <description>
        <![CDATA[
        Place number 2
        ]]>
        </description>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-72.661005,42.468222,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

The two files are in the same folder on my Google Drive. I tried replacing `<href>zzz.kml</href>` by the url `<href>https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bqcyrkqgNh9N8zKEr1gCI3o.../</href>`, without success.

It does not work (zzz.kml alone works very well, but I can not open it with init.kml).

**EDIT 1 :**

I tried loading a public file (http://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/Point.kml). Code of my file calling point.kml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<NetworkLink>
  <name>Loads Point.kml</name>
  <Link>
    <href>http://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/Point.kml</href>
  </Link>
</NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

It is a exemple from https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/updates.

It doesn't work either.

**EDIT 2 :**

I did a copy/paste of the code in Notepad++ and I save the file with kml extension. I import the file using "New Project" button > "Import KML file from computer". The file opens in Google Earth, but not the data :

[image]

When I copy download the file pbs_lcet_trails.kml and I open it directly using using "New Project" button > "Import KML file from computer", not via an other file, it works :

[image]

After I import the KML file, I open devTool and :

[image]

I noticed that I have the same errors when I directly import the KML file with data, except "Unknown RPC Service : picker".

About the fact to create an object, I tried, but I can not import a KML file in a project. I have to manually add data, and it is not a workable solution.

Thanks again for your time.

Comment: is the URL to the `.kml` on the drive publicly shared to _anyone_ with the URL?  It needs to be, otherwise it will not be reachable

Comment: Thanks blurfus. I can only share with my company domain. Public sharing is not allowed. It is not enough?

Comment: I do not believe so since the web app (google earth) does not reside within your company domain. It needs to access the URL from outside your company domain.

Comment: Thanks blurfus. Not a good news for me... I don't close the questions now, if somebody has another idea/workaround (but it seems hopeless if you're right). Thanks again.

Comment: You'd need to look at the documentation for Google Earth to see if they have an official channel / way to do it. https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/

Comment: I edited ma question, because I tried with a public file from Google, and it does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading a KML or KMZ file via NetworkLink in Google Earth for web requires that the file be publicly accessible on the internet, AND it requires that the host server send appropriate CORS headers with the file, allowing the Earth client code to load the file.  As a web app in the browser, Google Earth web enforces CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing), while the desktop app Earth Pro does not.

The issue with files on your company intranet is probably that they are not accessible on the public web, which is required for the Earth web client to be able to fetch and render them.

In the case of the public sample file you tried (http://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/Point.kml), it is NOT served with the correct CORS headers, since it was set up before Earth Web existed.

You can see the CORS errors in your browser's dev console, like at the bottom of this screenshot:
[image: KML NetworkLink CORS error screenshot]

To show that NetworkLinks can work in Earth web, here is a public KML file served with CORS headers, that should work:
https://www.gstatic.com/earthfeed/pbs/kml/pbs_lcet_trails.kml

And here is a sample KML NetworkLink that will load it (save this as a local KML file and load it into Earth web):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<NetworkLink>
  <name>Lewis and Clark Trails</name>
  <Link>
    <href>https://www.gstatic.com/earthfeed/pbs/kml/pbs_lcet_trails.kml</href>
  </Link>
</NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

Note that the requirements for public accessibility and CORS headers apply to many types of files loaded in Earth web, including image files used in balloons/panels, as overlays, or for icons; any audio or video files used in balloons; and of course any additional KML or KMZ files loaded via NetworkLinks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is very clear. Because I am not allowed to share publicly files, I have to forget this idea. But I am curious and I tried to open pbs_lcet_Trails.kml via a file with the above mentionned code, and it does not work. I have the error : "earthwasm.js:1 WebGL: INVALID_ENUM: getParameter: invalid parameter name
emscriptenWebGLGet @ earthwasm.js:1" and "DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://earth.google.com/static/9.154.0.1/polyfills/web-animations-next-lite.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE"

Comment: Continuation of my previous comment : and I have the two errors each time I try to load a file with network link. I don't think Google Earth Web is the cause for this problem. Anyway, thank you very much. Because of my compagny domain (a google domain, but not public), I am stuck. Thank you for your explanations.

Comment: Hi, at what step are you seeing those errors? Can you confirm that you took the KML code I provided above, put it into a text editor and saved it out as a KML file, and then loaded that into Earth web using "New Project" button > "Import KML file from computer"?  Does the KML load into a project correctly (appears in the project panel?

Comment: Also, you should be able to create a Project in Earth web (cloud/drive based project, not a local KML), and share that just within your organization.  Unfortunately Earth web does not yet support NetworkLinks in cloud projects, but it does support basic point/line/polygons.

Comment: @ChristiaanAdams: Did you see the OP’s response? It was posted as a separate answer, and will thus likely be deleted as _NAA_. It’s obviously difficult to accommodate that type of response (e.g., with images) via comments. Hopefully you’ll see it before it’s removed.

Comment: I did not see the OP's answer before it was removed.  @adblayrog, can you reply again in a comment?  If you want to add images, I think you should be able to edit the original question to add them.

Comment: @ChristiaanAdams: I edited my original question with the hidden answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @adblayrog, thx for the additional info.  Since they're yellow, those are just Warnings, not Errors. And I'm seeing those exact same 2 warnings when I first load Earth web, before I load any KML, so they're almost certainly unrelated to your KML issues. My current guess is that maybe your work computer or network has some security setting that is preventing the Earth client from fetching the KML specified in the NetworkLink... but just a guess.  You probably checked this, but did you zoom to N.America and confirm if the data is shown or not?  Did you expand the arrow in the list view?

Comment: @ChristiaanAdams. Yes, I did zoom and I did expand the arrow : no data. You may be right about the security. We have a lot of constraints, and it is possible that Google earth is affected. Thanks for explaining warning messages. And thanks a lot for all the time you passed here. I have to give up for Google Earth, but you were very helpfull.

Comment: Sorry to hear Google Earth won't work under the restrictions you face.  Good luck.